# AngularJS-2 cambiar los delimitadores {{ }}

Tags: angular2-template, angularjs-2.0

Estoy tratando de usar algo similar a `interpolateProvider` en `AngularJS 2` pero no puedo encontrar algo similar a esto:

AngularJS 1.x [$interpolateProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider)

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
```

Mirando la documentacion para`AngularJS 2` no pude encontrar algo parecido a lo anterior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

se puede cambiar incluyendo la propiedad interpolation en @component, ejemplo:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
    interpolation: ['[[', ']]']
})

export class AppComponent 
{
    title: string = "Angular 2 App";
    paragraph: string = "Nueva app con paso de variables";
}
```

con esto cambiamos los {{ }} por [[ ]]

Answer (score 5):

Por lo que he visto no tiene pinta de que sea configurable (por ahora).

Lo único a lo que he llegado, mirando el código, es que tienen definida una variable interna con la expresión regular que se correspondería con la expresión de interpolación, valga la redundancia.

El código es este:

[L51: modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/parser.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9b0e10e9a749791be66c2330a21bd7fb5253f8ad/modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/parser.ts#L51)

```
// TODO(tbosch): Cannot make this const/final right now because of the transpiler...
var INTERPOLATION_REGEXP = /\{\{([\s\S]*?)\}\}/g;
```

[L21: modules/angular2/src/compiler/legacy_template.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9e44dd85ada181b11be869841da2c157b095ee07/modules/angular2/src/compiler/legacy_template.ts#L21)

```
var INTERPOLATION_REGEXP = /\{\{.*?\}\}/g;
```

No sé si cambiando el valor de estas variables se podría conseguir lo que buscas (claro que después tendrías que re-compilar `angular2`).

Tampoco sé si conforme evolucione lo harán configurable.  Si te interesa mucho, registra un "issue" interesándote por la funcionalidad *(ventajas de los proyectos OSS)*, luego ya que le hagan caso o no es otra cosa.

A mí personalmente me preocupan los cambios en la sintaxis para bindear eventos, ... aunque parece que hay utilidades para poderlo migrar o también se podrá mezclar ng1 y ng2. Habrá que ir estando atentos.

**Actualización 10/02/2016:** En el enlace que ha compartido @AngelAngel en los comentarios se puede ver como ya hay un Issue abierto sobre este tema "[Ability to change the interpolation delimiter character #3682](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3682)"

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, al final opte por cambiar la del otro frame, y dejando a AngulaJS2 con estas, pero gracias por poner la info, si te interesa aqui se muestra algo sobre el tema -> http://victorsavkin.com/post/119943127151/angular-2-template-syntax Saludos

Comment: +1 y la aceptare, y si aparece una solucion y es publicada ya se cambiara, para que se encuentre mas rapido, o se podria hacer un update a su respuesta Saludos

Comment: igual si esta interasado puede mirar esto otro -> https://github.com/alfonso-presa/angular/commit/423b481f8de4a2ac6a24cd67d372b938f783a014 Saludos

Comment: Hola @AngelAngel son interesantes los enlaces que has compartido, me los guardo. En cuanto a la pregunta, estoy deacuerdo contigo, queda aquí y, si cambia algo, pues ya se actualizará o se contestará por otra persona. Saludos

Comment: hace tiempo que no uso Angular 2, pero hoy publicaron una respuesta, saludos